# How do I determine if Tempfile is a stream or not?

Tags: ruby, roo

I have a problem with roo gem. When I upload the file using my Rails app it ends up as a Tempfile on the file system, because I do not want to keep the file but import the spreadsheet data from it.

https://github.com/roo-rb/roo/blob/3ed05e1caef0ce3c5db5c19f1fa14e6f74193079/lib/roo/base.rb#L374

The above line checks if my object responds to seek. And that leads to a problem.

```
(byebug) filename_or_stream.class
Tempfile

(byebug) filename_or_stream.methods.include? :seek
true
```

How do you suggest I should go round this problem?

## I have tried to suppress the error

https://github.com/bigos/roo/commit/55ec3325ec3131fa34c3e0f5e647160cb17ef114

and was able to continue with my work, but the question still remains, How did the Tempfile get the seek method?

Looking for seek leads to this line

https://github.com/roo-rb/roo/blob/3ed05e1caef0ce3c5db5c19f1fa14e6f74193079/lib/roo/open_office.rb#L372

which makes no sense to me and I still do not know why Tempfile responds to seek if the documentation does not say anything about it.

## application illustrating the problem

https://github.com/bigos/open_example/blob/master/spec/models/open_sheet_spec.rb

## possible simple solution

```
if file.is_a? Tempfile
  @workbook = Roo::OpenOffice.new(file.path)
else
  @workbook = Roo::OpenOffice.new(file)
end
```

But why it was only a problem with Opensheet part of the roo gem? I did not notice the problem in other spreadsheets.

Comment: What is the problem? Does it result in an error later on?

Comment: yes, later I get the error saying that the file is nil.

Comment: _"How did the Tempfile get the seek method?"_ – I think `Tempfile` delegates to the underlying `File` object. From the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html): _"So although this class does not explicitly document all instance methods supported by File, you can in fact call any File instance method on a Tempfile object."_

Comment: @Stefan: damn, you're a second too fast :)

Comment: _"error saying that the file is nil"_ – maybe the tempfile was closed and therefore deleted?

Comment: Thanks, but that means we are back to starting point with proper stream determination. Am I right?

Comment: Suppressing the error has let me continue. Are you saying that the file might be deleted before I read the content?

Comment: "with proper stream determination" - not sure what you're trying to accomplish with that. Tempfile is a perfectly seekable IO object. roo should work just with off of it.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? It's hard to give advice without seeing the code.

Comment: Then probably the question should be about roo gem and how did I get to this problem.

Comment: @Stefan, I will do a quick detour to my work and will start working on the example in 5-10 minutes

Comment: @Stefan, I got the app ready to play

Comment: Just so you know, one of your examples there passes an IO object, the other - filename string. Not exactly equivalent, are they?

Comment: @Sergio, https://github.com/roo-rb/roo has the example of passing a string to the gem, which has 3 sub-components for OpenSheet, new Excel  and old excel. The problem was noticed only with Opensheet files.

Comment: All of the examples in the roo readme use filenames, not opened files. This agrees with your tests (the one that works uses the filename)